# ubuntu slow startup time - modprobe?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, modprobe, dmesg

I have setup my laptop with Ubuntu 11.04. I bought a fresh SSD, and expected the startup time at <30 seconds but it takes about 3-5 minutes.

I have taken a snapshop using bootchart but I don't know exactly how to read it:

[image]

For me, it looks like modprobe is running in some sort of timeout - but where can I check this?

The boot from dmesg:

> http://pastie.org/1937104

Comment: i was very happy to see my own post about this 1 year later since i reinstalled ubuntu and then i searched for "slow startup time ubuntu modprobe" i did not remember this specific fix horray for superuser!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently one driver (tpm_tis) was blocking the startup. i tried editing /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash tpm_tis.interrupts=0"
```

but this did not work, dmesg did the same output.

but then i disabled the module tpm_tis alltogether by adding

```
blacklist tpm_tis
```

to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf this pushed startup down to 17s after bios - 31 seconds from cold start

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this bug report: [tpm_tis 00:0a: tpm_transmit: tpm_send: error -62](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=530393) (for Fedora, but since it's kernel related could apply to Ubuntu).

The workaround for the issue seems to be to add

```
tpm_tis.interrupts=0
```

to the kernel command line.

(If that doesn't work for you, make sure you have the latest update of the Ubuntu kernel installed.)

Comment: That did not work..

Comment: do you have the latest ubuntu kernel? did the `dmesg` output change at all?